# Is particle board suitable as a subfloor patch?

Tags: flooring, joists, subfloor, carpentry, pine

I'd like to confirm that these missing bits of floorboard should have been replaced with some new sections of pine planks with the same thickness and grade.

In my new flat whoever installed the new heating system used what appears to be just some random bit of scrap wood. It was like chipwood--the cheap fake wood you get on kitchen cabinets--which definitely shouldn't have been used to bear weight. Or am I wrong?

Am I fair in saying that's bad that my washing machine goes on top of that? I understand that its mostly the joist that take the weight from the floor but aren't floorboards meant to then go on top to spread the weight evenly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nobody likes to discover shoddy workmanship, but in order to answer your question, you need to ask a clear, concise question. Unfortunately, our crystal balls are no better tuned than yours and we can't divine the worker's intent or mindset any better than you can. Unless you paid for the work that was left like this, then you're stuck with it. If it's a rental flat, though, complain to the landlord should be the one to repair it (he may not even know it was left like this). If you own, then it is on you to address it.

Comment: That said, in your first picture, there does appear to be a piece of plywood or similar that's covering the gaps in the floor. If it's of sufficient thickness (3/4" - 18mm - or more), then it's likely that this will sufficiently take the weight of a washing machine, since the feet would be at the corners and likely over the subfloor and onto the joists - the plywood just covering the holes. It would _not_ be pretty, nor professional, but would do the job until you got this properly repaired.

Comment: @FreeMan  If I wanted to bet, would say that plywood is closer to thin underlayment than 3/4.

Comment: You're probably right, @crip659, I was just pointing out that it could be a temporary solution to this rant. If the existing plywood is thin, the purchase of a thicker piece could also be a short-term solution to getting the washer in place and clothes clean, while waiting on a long-term solution.

Comment: I've revised your post to ask a specific, objective question (and remove the rantish and speculative parts). Feel free to revise further.

Comment: Please post a closer photo of the patch. I'd like a positive identification. If it's particle board, that stuff fails readily in strips that narrow and should be replaced.

Comment: Looking at that white board more closely, @isherwood, the ragged edges do look like an on-site cut of laminated particle board. No matter what I do or which blade I use, my cuts in that stuff _always_ flake the laminate like that, so I'd estimate 99% likelihood that it is particle board and would agree 100% that it needs to be replaced with solid wood or plywood before it fails.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what was in the contract to install the heating system. Yes, the boards should have been replaced with the cutout pieced but by who. The heating replacement company might have agreed to do the work but the owner might have agreed to replace the boards and then just ignored it.
Do some checking around and raise these questions do the owners/landlords, etc.
If you decide to fix this yourself, do not use particle board. It will swell up at the first sign of moisture and since your washer's going on top, there will be moisture. I'd be using exterior grade plywood.